# Publish multiarray Python msg

Tags: ros, python, multiarray, msg, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I press a button of my joystick, I save one point [x y z r p y] if I press again I save another point.

Here, I save two points:

[[0.29845908995953135, 0.210860533103541, 1.2190388918130415, -2.746641670660039, -0.8329844111292952, 2.842403460148573], [0.29843708899253263, 0.2220901105357484, 1.2190362691066245, -2.7466506780478976, -0.8329799064852043, 2.842416429478355]]

I want to publish something like this:

file.msg

```
int32 points
float32[points][0] vector
float32[points][1] vector
float32[points][2] vector
float32[points][3] vector
float32[points][4] vector
float32[points][5] vector
```

If I use std_msgs/Float32MultiArray.msg

```
MultiArrayLayout  layout        
float32[][0]  vector
float32[][1]  vector
float32[][2]  vector
float32[][3]  vector
float32[][4]  vector
float32[][5]  vector
```

So, Currently only support 1-dimensional array types. How solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204524/publish-multiarray-python-msg/) by [astur](https://answers.ros.org/users/20087/astur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-03-09

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should probably use ROS data types instead of trying to just have a multi-dimensional array of floats. This would make it much easier to directly interpret what's inside each message.

What you really want to do is send a list of poses (= translation + orientation), correct? In that case, your message could look like this:

`MyPoseList.msg`

```
Header header
geometry_msgs/Pose[] poses
```

To get the x dimension of the first pose, you would write `mymsg.poses[0].position.x`.

Two more things:

- Rotations are encoded as quaternions in ROS, not as Euler angles (roll-pitch-yaw). The `Pose` message has a `orientation` field that's a quaternion. Please search other answers here that explain how to convert between quaternions and Euler angles.
- A pose doesn't mean anything if you don't know *at what time* and in *what reference frame* it is specified, that's why you need the `header` field. It would perhaps be better to remove the `header` field and instead use `PoseStamped` messages; that way, you could specify a different time stamp for each pose.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2015-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [astur](https://answers.ros.org/users/20087/astur/) on 2015-03-09**:
Is there any other solution to use multiarrays?

I don't want to covert quaternions and also get time and reference frame, so if no other solution  i will create my own msg

Values.msg

```
float32 x
float32 y
float32 z
float32 r
float32 p
float32 y
```

Points.msg

```
Values[] vector
```

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-03-09**:
MultiArrays are meant for multi-dimensional arrays, usually of a fixed size, like images with RGB channels (640x480x3). Just look at the comments in `MultiArrayLayout.msg`. In your case, a list of message types (Pose[] or Values[]) is better.

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-03-09**:
Re your own message: Sure, as a quick and dirty hack, that's fine. You can still do it properly later.

**Comment by [Redhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/34008/redhwan/) on 2022-05-12**:
@ Martin Günther,
Do those problems have any solution??
[First one](https://answers.ros.org/question/400503/how-to-publish-and-subscribe-to-the-list-consisting-of-many-tuples/) and
[Second one](https://answers.ros.org/question/400444/how-to-publish-and-subscribe-to-the-dictionary/).

Please your opinion because I gave up.

I did not find similar to them in [your test code](https://github.com/uos/rospy_message_converter/blob/master/test/test_message_converter.py)